# Best Free software for hosting user guides

Tags: cms, mediawiki, guide

After having to clean up spam from a MediaWiki install for the umpteenth time, despite a recaptcha plugin "preventing" automated signups, I'm wondering if MediaWiki is the right choice as a CMS for hosting user manuals and guides.

I've always loved the way wikis can let the guides be edited and commented on collaboratively, but I'm getting tired of dealing with automated vandals. I've disabled edits & signups for now, but as I'm having to go through the pain of cleaning thousands of junk pages, I'm beginning to think I should cut my losses and look for a better alternative.

Does anyone know of suitable a FOSS application (preferably PHP / MySQL based) that would be simple for a non-coder (our manual writer) to edit, but that has all the interconnectivity, and searchability of a wiki? Or should I just bite the bullet again and lock the wiki down even further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lock the wiki down further. Assuming you know everyone who will be authoring content, there is no reason to allow drive-by edits or even signups - only sysops should be able to create accounts and only editors should use accounts.

Your users shouldn't be given access to change the documentation which they depend upon (just give them an easy way to contact support if the documentation proves to be insufficient to their needs).

[How can I secure an installation of MediaWiki?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2512/how-can-i-secure-an-installation-of-mediawiki) might be a good Q/A to review.

Comment: Thanks for that - looks like it's the way to go. I wanted to provide some way to facilitate user-user discussion, but the Talk pages have just been abused, so I guess it's time to get draconian! Excellent useful link too!